# Dealing with rich vocabulary and a low average frequency of words in NLP

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, tfidf

What is the best way to deal with a dataset that has a rich vocabulary and a low average frequency of words that is showing low validation accuracy?
While reading online I saw many people recommending removing stop-words and stemming while others suggested using a TF-IDF vectorizer.

Which solution will have the greater impact?

Answer (score 0):

The techniques you mention *may* be appropriate but the perspective and overall approach should likely be different.

*If* the data can be compressed while retaining the essence of its semantics then you will want to do that.  That is likely the case for:

- removing stop words
- stemming

But you will need to evaluate to *ensure* that is the case.  Is the transformed document retaining the original sense in your cases?  Once again the likelihood is that it is - but you should manually check what actually happened to see whether the stemming and stop words removal give semantic results that you are satisfied with. You should then evaluate to what extent the scoring against your metrics improve

Comment: So, it's a case-dependent situation and data must be checked after each step?

Comment: My experiences were that you want to check the results to see if they're what you / the stakeholders want.  If you have clear understanding that's encoded in testcases / test data sufficiently then that step is not necessary. But most likely the first step is needed and then decisions can be made and encoded, so that step can't be skipped altogether